# wrong time when creating Time object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

So I have a `Restaurant` model with two `time` columns:

```
t.time "opens"
t.time "closes"
```

When I create a Restaurant from my admin interface (using [Rails Admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin)) It seems that the correct time is taken into account (e.g. 12:00) but on my website and in the admin interface it is displayed with one more hour (13:00).

Here is some interesting console output:

```
irb(main):003:0> Restaurant.first
=> #<Restaurant id: 1, name: "Afrofoods", closes: "2000-01-01 14:00:00", opens: "2000-01-01 12:00:00", created_at: "2019-01-03 15:24:02", updated_at: "2019-01-03 15:24:02">

irb(main):004:0> Restaurant.first.opens
=> Sat, 01 Jan 2000 13:00:00 CET +01:00

irb(main):005:0> Time.now
=> 2019-01-03 16:31:54 +0000
```

It's probably a matter of timezone, as I am in France an my servers are in the UK. But how should I manage this ? Should I save my Restaurants in my DB by setting each time object with one hour less ? Or should I try to change something in the code ?

PS: I do not care about the date; I'm only using the time.

Comment: try changing your application's timezone. Look at https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html, Rails will take care of how the time is saved in the database.

Comment: That's a good idea @fanta, however I've tried to add `config.time_zone = "Paris"` but it did not solve the problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always save time in UTC to the database. And then you can manage time zones in Rails app. As an example, you can add a time zone column to the current user/admin record  and add around_action to the application controller or just specify the time zone in app settings.

```
    around_action :set_time_zone

    private

    def set_time_zone
      Time.use_zone(current_user.timezone) { yield }
    end
```

Note: better to use Time.current over Time.now if time zones are relevant for your project. Time.current the sake as Time.zone.now

Comment: Hi @Petro Yakubiv, thank you for your help ! how to I actually save time in UTC ?

Comment: @JulesCorb just remove timezone settings from your application.rb . Rails sets the UTC by default.

Comment: I did remove my timezone settings although it still prints time in CET :( weird. Timezones aren't relevant to my business as I only operate in France, It's just that I'd like to upload my Restaurants without having that additional hour that gets added to my `opens` and `closes` columns.

Comment: update: just found out rails saves my time in CET in production and in UTC in development.

Comment: @JulesCorb try to restart a server.

Comment: if timezones are not relevent you can add config.time_zone = 'Paris' to the application.rb. This will set a default time zone for the project. And the 
database will use UTC, because config.active_record.default_timezone  sets UTC as default.  And then you will not need to use around action

Comment: Thank you @Petro Yakubiv ! I actually also had `config.active_record.default_timezone = :local` and removing it did the trick. It now works perfectly. thank you again mate !